# onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) does not work

Tags: android, android-menu

The Toast does not show up when I click on the Menu item. The button I defined in the Menu is unresponsive.

```
@Override
onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_menu, menu);
    MenuItem edit= menu.findItem(R.id.edit_page);
    edit.setVisible(true);
    return true;
}

@Override
onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    // The error was here! Sorry for my negligence
    if (id == R.id.edit_page) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not yet implemented!", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: you must override the methods

Comment: show your activity_menu xml too.

Comment: Where does 'id' in  " if (id == R.id.edit_page)" come from?

Comment: I did not post all the code due to many if statements...I was comparing the wrong ID. Sorry :( and thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are propably comparing wrong id in method "onOptionsItemSelected" .

```
if (id == R.id.edit_page) {
```

should be

```
if (item.getItemId() == R.id.edit_page) {
```

Comment: guesses do not make good answers. Ask information from OP and then post answer.

Comment: Indeed I am comparing the wrong ID....very embarrassing. Thank you! I have many if statements in there...didn't want to post all the code

Answer (score -1):

id is not defined in your code

```
 onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

     int id = item.getItemId(); //Add this line 

    if (id == R.id.edit_page) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not yet implemented!", 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please edit your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.

Comment: It is easily understandable but i dont know why you can`t @I